# Data points not plotting on map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot data points on a map of the UK.

I am using this shapefile
https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/127c4bda06314409a1fa0df505f510e6_0/explore?location=53.335969%2C-0.556351%2C5.00

If I compare the longitude and latitude on the shapefile in R, they are not different from my data points like in the plot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JS05.png)

I used this data points file and converted easting/northing to longitude/latitude
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4x7q.png)

```
library(tidyverse)

library(sf)

a<-read.csv('eastnorthtest.csv')

a <- a %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("latitude", "longitude"), crs = 27700) %>% st_transform(4326) %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  as_tibble()

eng_reg_map <- 
  st_read("LAD_DEC_2023_UK_BFC.shp")

eng_reg_map |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(colour = "black",fill='white') + 
  geom_point(data = a, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), size = 1, colour = 'red')
```

Comment: Why are you converting `a` to a simple tibble object? You can try to plot `a` as an `sf` object using also `geom_sf`.

Comment: Are you sure the CRS of map and a are the same? What's the result of `sf::st_crs(a) == sf::st_crs(eng_reg_map)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRS of the map you have downloaded is ESPG 27700. It seems that your original co-ordinates from the csv were already in this projection, yet for some reason you have changed them into ESPG 4326. This means that when you plot the points, ggplot thinks you want these numbers to represent meters from the OS origin, not degrees longitude and latitude.

The safest way to prevent this kind of thing is to convert your points to an sf object:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

eng_reg_map <- st_read(shp_path)

a <- data.frame(eastings = c(-0.15081, -0.15489), 
                northings = c(50.8465, 50.8268))

points <- st_multipoint(as.matrix(a)) |>
  st_sfc(crs = 4326) |>
  st_transform(27700)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = eng_reg_map) +
  geom_sf(data = points, color = 'red')
```

[image]